# Real solution that can only be written in closed form using $i$?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Using Mathematica I sought solutions to the following equation:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{x}{8(1+x)^2} + \frac{x^3}{6(1+x)^2} + \frac{1}{8(1+x)} - \frac{x^2}{2(1+x)}\right) = 0$$

Three solutions were obtained. <s>Two were imaginary</s> and the following real solution was obtained:

$$x= \frac{1}{2} \left(-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}
   \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(1+i
   \sqrt{3}\right)}\right) \approx 0.4397$$

However it surprising to me that this root is real yet is written in closed form containing the imaginary number $i$.

If this is indeed a correct and real root then should it be possible to manipulate the above expression to cancel the imaginary component $i$? Or are there some real numbers that can only be written in terms of the imaginary component $i$?

Comment: I think you have rediscovered an instance of [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis).

Comment: The equation is $8 x^3 + 12 x^2 - 3 x - 6 = 0$, which has Galois group $S_3$ (courtesy PARI/GP).

Comment: I suppose a typo somewhere since the third and fourth terms are identical. As written, the solution is wrong.

Comment: Yes it was a typo. I accidentally repeated the 3rd term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That equation reduces to $8 x^3 + 12 x^2 - 3 x - 6 = 0$, which has $3$ real roots and has no rational roots.

Therefore, this is an instance of [Casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis), meaning that the solutions cannot be expressed with real radicals alone.

Comment: The equation is not $8 x^3 + 12 x^2 - 3 x - 6 = 0$ but $8 x^3 + 12 x^2 - 3 = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the trigonometric method for solving cubic equation, you should notice that
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(1+i
   \sqrt{3}\right)}=\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)+i \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}
   \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}}=\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)-i \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)$$ making $$x=\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\approx 0.439693$$

Comment: So it turns out that the root can be written without $i$. Is this really *casus irreducibilis* then?

Comment: @JackPierce-Brown. I would prefer to avoid semantics issues.

Comment: @Jack Pierce-Brown Yes it is *casus irreducibilis* because you can display other roots with the same "mould". The fact that you can express the root without $i$ isn't a criteria (as there is at least one real root, one of them can be expressed without "i").

Comment: More precisely, but still intuitively, the term *casus irreducibilis* means the root cannot be written by "algebraic methods" without *i*. A more workable definition is that the root cannot be expressed by a finite sequence of applications of the 4 basic arithmetic operations, and any of the various $n$'th root extractions only applied to real numbers that also produce real number results, beginning with the rational numbers (or with the field generated by the rational numbers and the coefficients of the equation, if you want to allow the equation to have coefficients such as pi or something).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro. for sure, I totally agree with you ... in a general manner.   Thanks for the comment. Cheers.

Comment: In [this 26 September 2005 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=3977641) archived at Math Forum, I posted a lot of historical information and references about this issue.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro. This is a fantastic material ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The closed form is  $$  \frac{1}{2} \left(-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}
   \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(1+i
   \sqrt{3}\right)}\right)= \frac{1}{2}( 2cos(\pi /9)-1)$$Let use the polar form of $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}}=e^{-\pi /9 i}=cos(-\pi /9)+isin(-\pi /9)  $$and$${\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}}=e^{\pi /9 i}= cos(\pi /9)+isin(\pi /9)  $$ The rest is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first agree that the issue can be simplified into:

$$\tag{1}8 x^3 + 12 x^2 - 3=0$$

let us deepen the link of these solutions with circular functions (see solution by @Claude Leibovici).

It is well known that $\cos(n \theta)$ can be expressed as a $n$-th degree polynomial in $\cos \theta$, named $T_n(\cos \theta)$ and called the $n$th Chebyshev polynomial. Let us consider the case $n=9$ : setting $x=\cos \theta$, we can factor $T_9(x)+1$ in the following way:

$$P(x):=T_9(x)+1=(x+1)(2x-1)^2(8x^3-6x-1)^2$$

(thanks to Wolfram Alpha). What are the roots of $P$ connected to ?

Otherwise said, when is $\cos(9 \theta)=-1 $ ? (we will only consider values $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$).

- Equation $(x+1)=0$ corresponds to $x=-1$ i.e., $\theta=\pi$.
- Equation $(2x-1)^2=0$ corresponds to the double root $x=\pm \tfrac12$ i.e., $\theta=\pm \tfrac{\pi}{3}$.

and last but not least:

- Equation $Q(x)^2=0$ with $Q(x):=8x^3-6x-1$ corresponds to the 6 remaining roots $\theta=\pm\tfrac{\pi}{9}, \pm\tfrac{4\pi}{9}, \pm\tfrac{5\pi}{9}.$ grouped by 3.

Thus $Q(x)$ appears as a key polynomial in this issue with roots  $\tag{2}\cos(\pm\tfrac{\pi}{9}), \cos(\pm\tfrac{5\pi}{9}), \cos(\pm\tfrac{7\pi}{9}).$

It suffices now to make a shift, i.e. consider

$$Q(x+\tfrac12)=8 x^3 + 12 x^2 - 3$$

We retrieve the polynomial in the LHS of (1) with roots obtained from (2):

$$-\tfrac12+\cos \tfrac{\pi}{9} \approx 0.4397,   \ -\tfrac12+\cos\tfrac{5\pi}{9} \approx -1.2660, \ -\tfrac12+\cos\tfrac{7\pi}{9} \approx   -0.6736.$$